# Adding an Extra link in Open Graph Post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

We are making an Article Reading app with Open Graph. When ever user reads any article on the App it gets posted as an Activity and his friends can see it.

The problem is if user clicks on the feed title, he is taken to the permission page and he has to grant the permission to read the article. I know that this is the core of Open Graph but we feel it would be great if we can provide a link like "Read Now" apart from usual post, which takes the user to the article directly without granting any permission. Obviously, he wont be able to see any friends activity on that page and it wont allow us to post on his behalf, but that is fine because users intention was just to read that particular article.

Has any one done something like this?

Any pointers would be really appreciated

Gaurav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're posting this link, if it's using the javascript sdk or from the servers, but the [Post object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) has the *actions* field which is:

> A list of available actions on the post (including commenting, liking,
>   and an optional app-specified action)

For example using the js sdk:

```
FB.ui({
    method: "feed",
    link: "LINK_URL",
    ...
    actions: [
        { name: "Read Now", link: "URL TO THE READ NOW " }
    ]
}, function(response) { console.log(response); });
```

You can obviously do the same if you post in different methods since it's all based on http requests.

Another thing is that you can completely go around all of this.
When a user comes to an article, check if he is authenticated, if he is no problem, otherwise show him message saying something like "you can read the article or log in, read it and share the social aspect of the experience.." and two options, continue to read or to install the app, if he chooses to install the app you then take him to the auth dialog.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That would definitely help. Is it possible to add this kind of "Read Now" in the Aggregator?

Comment: That's a good question, I don't think so. How are you going to implement the "Read Now" with the open graph? Is it a different *Action* then reading it with installing the app?

Comment: We have a simple Action named Read on Article Object. Now our App uses feeds to show content from other sites. So our Read now button will link to those sites directly. When we try to post using Graph API for Open Graph, we provide a simple action like you suggested in your code, but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: The open graph is still new and is lacking some things. I don't think that you can do what you want. You can't for example (as far as I'm aware) aggregate for more than one action, and I couldn't find anything about adding more links to the items in an aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

It's you thats in control of the authentication flow. If you have Auth'd referrals turned off, then when a user clicks an article link in feed, they'll be taken to your app. You can then decide if you want to auth them or not.

You could do one of three things:

- force the user to Auth the app to read the article. This ensures every reader can publish a read action which grows your app, but its an aggressive user-experience.
- not force the user to Auth the app to read the article. This offers a great UX (see story in feed, click, read story) but these un-auth'd users can't publish read actions so it makes it hard for your app to grow. Getting these user to auth after the've read the article is nigh-on impossible
- when the user lands on the article, show a modal dialog which ask the user if they want to authenticate. Make it really obvious that this is what you want them to do, and let them know the benefits (friends see what you're reading, you get to see what your friends are reading) - but this dilog includes a 'no thanks' option which just lets them read the article un-auth'd.

Some apps Like The Guardian as the user to auth before they read the article, But if the user presses 'Cancel' in the Auth dialog, they set a cookie and redirect them to the article in a non-social context on guardian.co.uk. The cookie means that the next time they click on an article in newsfeed, they'll bypass the social app and read the content directly on guardian.co.uk. This way, users who want a social experience get one, those who don't: don't.